# PHP Printing multi dimension array

Tags: php

How to print this kind of array?

```
Array (
         [0] => Array ( 
                    [0] => 1144 [task_id] => 1144
                    [1] => Server rent [task_name] => Server rent
                     )
       )
```

Comment: How did you get this kind of array?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Its not really clear from your question what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to continue execution after printing:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

If you want to end execution (useful for debug purposes):

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
exit();
```

Comment: Thnx mate, helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `print_r();`
and you can use`echo "<pre>";print_r($array);echo "</pre>";`
For more information : [function print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)